# Comment-based help does not display content in .NOTES section

Tags: powershell

[According to TechNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/help/comment-based-help-keywords) one of the keywords for the comment-based help is `.Notes`. But when I include this keyword the corresponding help text is not displayed.

My script:

```
<#
.DESCRIPTION
This describes the script.

.NOTES
This is a note about the script.
#>

"Hello world"
```

Output of Get-Help:

```
PS E:\> Get-Help .\Test-Script.ps1

NAME
    E:\Test-Script.ps1

SYNOPSIS


SYNTAX
    E:\Test-Script.ps1 [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    This describes the script.


RELATED LINKS

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help E:\Test-Script.ps1 -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help E:\Test-Script.ps1 -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help E:\Test-Script.ps1 -full".
```

I *know* the .Notes keyword is being recognized because if I misspell it, say as ".NotesX", running Get-Help doesn't return *any* custom help:

> PS E:> Get-Help .\Test-Script.ps1
>   Test-Script.ps1

I looked for a custom switch that Get-Help might require before displaying this section, like the `-example` shows the content from the .Example keyword(s), but didn't find one. I'm trying this on PowerShell v5.1.

How can I get the .Notes section to display when Get-Help is run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `Get-Help Get-Help`

REMARKS

```
To see the examples, type: "get-help Get-Help -examples".
For more information, type: "get-help Get-Help -detailed".
For technical information, type: "get-help Get-Help -full".
For online help, type: "get-help Get-Help -online"
```

So you can use:

```
Get-Help .\Test-Script.ps1 -full
```

Comment: This stuff is why I hate Powershell.  I would expect -detailed to include notes.